# Parse multiple formats with date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I have this code example:

```
function compareDate(value: string) {
  return isBefore(
    parse(value, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date()),
    sub(new Date(), { days: 1 })
  );
}

const test = compareDate('31-12-2020');
```

in parse() I need to use `dd-MM-yyyy`, but also `dd/MM/yyyy` and `dd MM yyyy`. How can I achieve this?
The value will have date typed by user, typeof String and will look like above examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all possible separators with the correct one:

```js
function compareDate(value: string) {
  return isBefore(
    parse(value.replace(/[\/ ]/g, '-'), 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date()),
    sub(new Date(), { days: 1 })
  )
}

const test = compareDate('31-12-2020')
```

Comment: I've tried second example, but it's not working. I don't understand first example. The date will be in ```value```, typeof String, and I don't know if it will be with '-', '/' or ' '

Comment: I've updated an answer. I forgot global flag `/g` in regexp.

Comment: yes, this is working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: I have a new problem regarding this regex, it doesn't validate date format "01/01-1987". It should validate repeated "-" m "/" or " " Have any idea how should I modify this regex?

Comment: This is what it does, you don't have to add  `-` to regexp, cause it's already "replaced" with correct separator. I've checked regexp for `01/01-1987` and it correctly returns `01-01-1987`. Are you sure there is no other problem with your code? Cause this looks correct

Comment: I only have these regex for validating the data.. I think it needs something for repeated characters

Comment: What do you mean? How does the input value looks like (cause as said before works fine for `01/01-1987`). Feel free to create new question with examples for which it doesn't work.

Comment: I've created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684828/date-validation-issue with the code I have now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `isMatch` to determine which string you have:

```
function compareDate(value: string) {
  let start;
  if (isMatch(value, 'dd-MM-yyyy')) {
    start = parse(value, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());
  } else if (isMatch(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) {
    // etc...
  }
  return isBefore(
    start,
    sub(new Date(), { days: 1 })
  );
}
```

Comment: Looks promising for isMatch to validate date format